# Get the color value of any position in the shade

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to use `TikZ` to draw the following picture. I use the shadings library. I want to get the color value of any position in the shade. The following is my MWE and picture.

```tex
\documentclass[margin = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshading}{1cm}
{
    rgb(0cm)=(0.231, 0.298, 0.753);
    rgb(1cm)=(0.408, 0.541, 0.937);
    rgb(2cm)=(0.612, 0.741, 1.000);
    rgb(3cm)=(0.800, 0.851, 0.929);
    rgb(4cm)=(0.937, 0.808, 0.741);
    rgb(5cm)=(0.961, 0.631, 0.510);
    rgb(6cm)=(0.867, 0.373, 0.294);
    rgb(7cm)=(0.796, 0.310, 0.404)
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor = south west,inner sep = 0pt] at (0,0) {\pgfuseshading{myshading}};
    \foreach \x in {-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6} {
        \pgfmathparse{5 * \x + 4}
        \draw[] (1.2,\pgfmathresult) --++ (.3,0)node[right,font = \small]{\x};
    }  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would be much more convenient to use a matrix plot (see section **4.6.12 Image (Matrix) Plots** of the pgfplots manual) to produce this picture.

Comment: yeah, sure! But how to get the color value of any position in the shade

Comment: @ljguo: Can you provide a more descriptive title to your question, as opposed to "how to draw this?"

Comment: With the updated title: maybe you are looking for `/pgfplots/color of colormap` from  the pgfplots manual page 214?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to produce this plot you may want to use pgfplots (see section **4.6.12 Image (Matrix) Plots** of the pgfplots manual).

You can also use pgfplots to get the color data. First, define a colormap based on your shading. Then use `color of colormap` to convert a value on your chart into a color. And then use `xcolor` to extract the color information. The last step can be coded in a pgf function, which, among other things, converts a position on your chart to a number between 0 and 1000 to be able to use the `color of colormap` key.

```
\documentclass[margin = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{myshading}{1cm}
{
    rgb(0cm)=(0.231, 0.298, 0.753);
    rgb(1cm)=(0.408, 0.541, 0.937);
    rgb(2cm)=(0.612, 0.741, 1.000);
    rgb(3cm)=(0.800, 0.851, 0.929);
    rgb(4cm)=(0.937, 0.808, 0.741);
    rgb(5cm)=(0.961, 0.631, 0.510);
    rgb(6cm)=(0.867, 0.373, 0.294);
    rgb(7cm)=(0.796, 0.310, 0.404)
}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{colordata}{1}{\begingroup 
    \pgfmathparse{1000*#1/1.4+800/1.4}%
    \tikzset{color of colormap={\pgfmathresult}}%
    \extractcolorspec{.}\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult
\endgroup}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor = south west,inner sep = 0pt] at (0,0) {\pgfuseshading{myshading}};
    \foreach \x in {-0.8,-0.6,-0.4,-0.2,0.0,0.2,0.4,0.6} {
        \pgfmathparse{5 * \x + 4}
        \draw[] (1.2,\pgfmathresult) --++ (.3,0)node[right,font = \small]{\x};
    }  
    \pgfplotsset{colormap={mybluered}{rgb(0cm)=(0.231, 0.298, 0.753);
    rgb(1cm)=(0.408, 0.541, 0.937);
    rgb(2cm)=(0.612, 0.741, 1.000);
    rgb(3cm)=(0.800, 0.851, 0.929);
    rgb(4cm)=(0.937, 0.808, 0.741);
    rgb(5cm)=(0.961, 0.631, 0.510);
    rgb(6cm)=(0.867, 0.373, 0.294);
    rgb(7cm)=(0.796, 0.310, 0.404)}}
    
    \node[below=1em]{the color of the point $0.4$ on the chart is \pgfmathsetmacro\mycolordata{colordata(0.4)}\mycolordata};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]